# Order of execution of the UITableview delegate method

Tags: objective-c

What happens, when the execution enters the below uitableview delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

each time. Does this method set the height of a random row each time in executes this method? Or is the height set in chronological order of rows.

I mean, is it first row's height set first, then second row's height, then third row's and so on..
Or is it like some nth rows height set first, (n-5)th row set second, (n+2)nd row third and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chronically but only for rows in the visible view.

Comment: All of my rows are visible. I am setting the row height of my table according to the data from an array. That means, the first time the debugger enters the method, the first row's height is set and so on. Right?

Comment: This delegate will call for each of the row that are visible to user.If you scroll your table view, then this delegate will call again for further rows. You can put a breakpoint and can see how many times this delegate method called

Comment: I was talking about the first time when the table is created.